# Adding List Item Programmatically

Tags: 2010, custom-list, splistitem

I am working in SharePoint 2010.I am dynamically creating a list on FeatureActivation event.
My list has following columns Title : Text , VisibleTo: User/People, Menu : Choice, Type : Choice.

Problem is when I try to add items dynamically it gives me following error.

**Invalid data has been used to update the list item. The field you are trying to update may      be read only.**

As the error message suggest, there is no read only field in the list.

Please help me on finding the exact cause of this error.

```
oList.Fields.Add("LinkTitle", SPFieldType.Text, true);                     
oList.Fields.Add("URL", SPFieldType.Text, false);
oList.Fields.Add("ShowInNav", SPFieldType.Boolean, false);
oList.Fields.Add("VisibleTo", SPFieldType.User, false);
oList.Fields.Add("ParentID", SPFieldType.Text, false);


oListItem["Title"] = newListItem.Title;
oListItem["LinkTitle"] = newListItem.LinkTitle;
oListItem["URL"] = newListItem.URL;
oListItem["ShowInNav"] = newListItem.ShowInNav;
oListItem["VisibleTo"] = oWeb.EnsureUser("ABC");
oListItem["ParentID"] = newListItem.ParentId;
oListItem.Update();
```

Where newListItem is a collection of items.

Many thanks

VB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Steve comments it's hard to guess without any code. But my guess would be that the Person(s) inserted into VisibleTo isn't on the site. Try using [EnsureUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.ensureuser.aspx) before adding them.

OK after the code has been added it's a bit easier.

Remove the following lines :

```
oList.Fields.Add("LinkTitle", SPFieldType.Text, true);
```

and

```
oListItem["LinkTitle"] = newListItem.LinkTitle;
```

LinkTitle and LinkTitleNoMenu are two very special fields which has the same data as Title (and therefore shouldn't be updated), but different representation in views.

Comment: Hi Per I tried that but still I have the same error.Though user is present on site.

Comment: Thanks per. It worked after removing the Link Title column.